# How can I make a gallery that automatically fits photos like puzzle pieces?

Tags: html, css, alignment, gallery, article

I am attempting to create a website that will host my art, blogs, articles, and other media. I want the art (for the art) and the thumbnail (for the articles, etc.) to show at their relative shape. I can do that part by simply linking the images to a new page (either the art piece or the article).

What I am having trouble with, however, is fitting each inequilateral shape together relative to their size and where they are inserted on the main page of my HTML file. The included link is a website that I'll use as an example, and a picture is included for those on phones.

Website I'm basing off of: http://www.kogashuku.com/

[Picture for mobile devices](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mzcHN.png)

Comment: Flagging as too broad a question. Sorry but SO is for questions that target specific coding issues not freelancing requests.

Comment: Please go through the [tour], the [help] and the [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) sections to see how this site works and to help you improve your current and future questions, which can help you get better answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand what you're going for, you can use [Masonry.js](https://masonry.desandro.com/) for that.

You will have an easier time, and achieve a better result, if you leverage a polished, 3rd-party solution to help you.

Comment: Thanks Drew! Not a lot of people like you. Most give sarcastic answers or flag it for something they don't understand.